Get a list of all route helpers for a model dynamically in rails
I have a bunch of rails models, let's say one of them is called Post. I need a way to programmatically extract all route helpers with their respective method for a specific model.
Something like this
 Rails.application.routes.named_routes.helper_names.select do |n|
   n.include? "post"
 end  

obviously won't work, because I could have another model called OtherPost.
I would like to have something like
{
  {"method": "GET", "helper": "post_path", "action": "show"},
  {"method": "POST", "helper": "edit_post_path", "action": "update"},
  {"method": "GET", "helper": "posts_path", "action": "index"},
  ...
}

I know that the action and method are in Rails.application.routes.routes ->  route.verb and route.defaults[:action], but I can't seem to be able to reliably tie them to the helper name.

Route helpers are just methods that when called return a path (a string). Like posts_path -> "/posts". What you're looking for is a list of actual routes. It would help if you could tell us what the actual use case is since the question in itself is kind of broken.

There are a lot of problems with your idea.
A route helper is a method that just produces a path. It is not concerned with the HTTP verb. So what you're looking to list is not the helpers, it's the actual routes.
Rails derives the names of the routing helpers dynamically from models through the ActiveModel::Naming API.
irb(main):005:0> Post.model_name.route_key
=> "posts"
irb(main):006:0> Post.model_name.singular_route_key
=> "post"
irb(main):007:0> OtherPost.model_name.route_key
=> "other_posts"
irb(main):008:0> OtherPost.model_name.singular_route_key
=> "other_post"

However routes in Rails have no actual coupling to your models. The only thing that links the two is convention over configuration and any attempt to automatically map the two will only work as long as the routes follow those conventions. Your example output does not.
There is also no strong link between the route helpers and the route set. The helper methods are just generated for named routes when rails builds the route set.
Only some routes are named.
A route in Rails is an instance of ActionDispatch::Journey::Route. This route may be named or not and is really just a set of constraints based on the URI, http method, headers etc.
If you look at the conventional routes generated by resources :posts you can see that only the GET routes are named.
max@maxbox ~/p/sandbox_7 (main)> rails routes -c posts
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
    posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#index
          POST   /posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
          PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy

That's because creating uses the collection path (posts_path) and updating and destroying uses the member path (post_path). Since these paths are the same there is no sense in generating separate helpers for these routes.
So trying to look up the routes that way is fundamentially flawed.
Another slightly flawed assumption
If we can assume that the model name lines up with the controller name we could use that to filter the routes.
irb(main):008:0> post_routes = routes.filter { |r| r.defaults[:controller]&.match?('post') }  
irb(main):009:0> post_routes.map { |r| { name: r.name, pattern: r.path.spec.to_s, verb: r.verb, controller: r.defaults[:controller], action: r.defaults[:action] } }                                                                            =>
[{:name=>"posts", :pattern=>"/posts(.:format)", :verb=>"GET", :controller=>"posts", :action=>"index"},
 {:name=>nil, :pattern=>"/posts(.:format)", :verb=>"POST", :controller=>"posts", :action=>"create"},
 {:name=>"new_post", :pattern=>"/posts/new(.:format)", :verb=>"GET", :controller=>"posts", :action=>"new"},
 {:name=>"edit_post", :pattern=>"/posts/:id/edit(.:format)", :verb=>"GET", :controller=>"posts", :action=>"edit"},
 {:name=>"post", :pattern=>"/posts/:id(.:format)", :verb=>"GET", :controller=>"posts", :action=>"show"},
 {:name=>nil, :pattern=>"/posts/:id(.:format)", :verb=>"PATCH", :controller=>"posts", :action=>"update"},
 {:name=>nil, :pattern=>"/posts/:id(.:format)", :verb=>"PUT", :controller=>"posts", :action=>"update"},
 {:name=>nil, :pattern=>"/posts/:id(.:format)", :verb=>"DELETE", :controller=>"posts", :action=>"destroy"}]

However again the devil is in the details as this only works when the model name lines up with the controller name. You don't have to go further than for example adding Devise to your application before this starts breaking down. Additionally you get an additional level of complexity when dealing with namespaced routes.
TLDR
There is no 100% reliable way to get the routes related to a model as that link is pretty weak. All you can do is make guesses.
Also beware that models are an internal implementation detail of an application while routes are the external API your application provides to the world. While the two may be the same in simple CRUD apps this is not always the case.
If what you're looking to do is just audit the routes a much simpler solution is just rails routes -c posts.

+1 for this answer from Max. Some Guy your questions suggests you're about to go down an implementation path that'll cause you headaches in the future.
You're coupling internal abstractions to your API, don't do this.

Rails.application.routes.routes returns a list of ActionDispatch::Journey::Route elements that are, unfortunately, not well documented. But taking a look into the source code help to find method that return what you are looking for.
The following is close to what you are looking for:
Rails.application.routes.routes.map do |route| 
  { method: route.verb, helper: route.name, action: route.requirements[:acction] } 
end

Keep in mind that not all routes have all desired attributes, depending on how they were defined. They might for example not be named.

Is this what you want?
def extract_routes_for_model(model_name)
  Rails.application.routes.routes.map do |route|
    verb = route.verb.match(/[A-Z]+/).to_s
    path = route.path.spec.to_s
    controller_action = route.defaults[:controller]
    action = route.defaults[:action]
    helper = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.method_defined?("#{route.name}_path") ? "#{route.name}_path" : nil

    if controller_action&.include?(model_name.underscore.pluralize)
      {
        method: verb,
        path: path,
        helper: helper,
        action: action
      }
    end
  end.compact
end

Use: extract_routes_for_model("Post")
The output will be an array of hashes containing information for each corresponding path.

That's a very clever (not in a good way) solution but will only cover the case where the controller and model match up. Its pretty redundant - you don't need to assign a variable for stuff thats just used once. route.verb.match(/[A-Z]+/).to_s is complete nonsense. If you look at my answer the same thing can be done in a oneliner.
